# Getting a document.body error. help!

Tags: javascript, html, notifications

I have the following JavaScript code:

```
function createNotification(title, body, canDismiss, callback)
{
    //create the container
    var nContainer = document.createElement("div");
    nContainer.setAttribute("id", "note"+title);
    nContainer.setAttribute("class","nContainer");
    nContainer.className = "nContainer";

    //create the title
    var nTitle = document.createElement("div");
    nTitle.setAttribute("class", "nTitle");
    nTitle.className = "nTitle";
    nTitle.innerHTML = title;

    //if canDismiss is true then add controls
    if (canDismiss)
    {
        var nDismiss = document.createElement("div");
        nDismiss.setAttribute("class", "nDismiss");
        nDismiss.className = "nDismiss";
        nDismiss.innerHTML = "[close]";
        nDismiss.onclick = function(){destroyNotification(title);callback();};
        nTitle.appendChild(nDismiss);

    }

    //append the title to the container
    nContainer.appendChild(nTitle);

    //create the body and append to container
    var nBody = document.createElement("div");
    nBody.setAttribute("class", "nBody");
    nBody.className = "nBody";
    nBody.innerHTML = body;
    nContainer.appendChild(nBody);

    document.body.appendChild(nContainer);

    //fade background
    fadeIt(title);
}

function destroyNotification(title)
{
    //get the specified notification
    var note = document.getElementById("note"+title);

    //remove the notification
    document.body.removeChild(note);

    //unfade the background
    unfadeIt(title)
}

function fadeIt(title)
{
    //create a partially opaque div and append it to the document
    var Fade = document.createElement("div");
    Fade.setAttribute("id", "fade"+title);
    Fade.setAttribute("class","fade");
    Fade.className = "fade";
    document.body.appendChild(Fade);
}

function unfadeIt(title)
{
    //get the specified fade element
    var Fade = document.getElementById("fade"+title);

    //remove the specified fade element
    document.body.removeChild(Fade);
}
```

I am getting a document.body error. Can anyone please help?

This is the html:

```
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
<script langauge="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="notification.js"> </script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="notification.css" /> 
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">

createNotification("The Title", "Some sort of message for our body", true, function(){alert("A Callback");});


</script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

The error I got from firebug is:

> document.body is null
>
> [Break on this error] document.body.appendChild(nContainer);

Comment: Which method? Called with what parameters? For what specific markup already in the page? And what's the error method and what line does it occur on? *Help us help you!* :=)

Comment: createNotification("The Title", "Some sort of message for our body", true, function(){alert("A Callback");});

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're executing the function `createNotification` before the page is even loaded. The `body` element doesn't even exist when you call it.

Call the function on the bottom of the page or add a load event [[link]](http://www.onlinetools.org/articles/unobtrusivejavascript/chapter4.html).

Answer (score 0):

There is property "body" for document object.

```
document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].removeChild(note);
```

Answer (score 0):

When are you executing your code? I mean, when are the methods getting called: after the document has loaded or somewhere before? Also I could not understand one line of code in createNotification:

```
function nBody.innerHTML = body;
```

Can you call this method inside the body tag instead of the head tag? Or can you use a `window.onload` event to call this function?

Comment: this is more of a comment than an answer, it'd be better removed and added as one =)

Comment: this is rather a hint that you are probably calling your function before the page has loaded and that can be a reason for the error. Instead of directly telling what the reason is.